# super slow R sapply loop

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I tried to calculate the pairwise identity rate for two sequences. If my data is in the format of:

```
nrow(mydata_v)  
[1] 1145


mydata_v[1:10,1:10]  
V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14  
A1 "M" "E" "T" "I" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A2 "M" "E" "A" "V" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A3 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"  
A4 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"  
A5 "M" "E" "T" "T" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A6 "M" "E" "T" "T" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A7 "M" "E" "T" "I" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A8 "M" "E" "T" "I" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"  
A9 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"  
A10 "M" "E" "T" "I" "S" "L" "I" "T" "I" "L"
```

**yeah agree with Aaron Schumacher that my code was not doing the right thing**
**updated working code and now spped seems okay**

```
mydata_v =as.matrix( mydata[,4:( ncol(mydata)-2)])  
mydata_v[mydata_v=="-"] =NA  
loop_fun <-function(p) {  
    v1 =as.vector(mydata_v[p[1],])  
    v2 =as.vector(mydata_v[p[2],])  
    good_pos =complete.cases(v1,v2)  
    identity =(100*sum(v1[good_pos]!=v2[good_pos])/sum(good_pos))  
}  
m_pair =as.data.frame( combn(1:nrow(mydata_v),2) )  
hot_vector =sapply(m_pair, loop_fun)  
hot <- diag(nrow(mydata_v)-1)  
hot[lower.tri(hot,diag=T)] <- hot_vector
```

Thanks a lot,
Shuoguo

Comment: I don't see anything within `loop_fun()` that is too glaringly bad. Although referring to datasets not within the scope of a function is bad practice. `vapply` is marginally faster than `sapply` if you specify the output class. Your biggest problem is that your `m_pair` is absolutely massive, so your loop essentially becomes nearly endless even with 'merely' 500 rows of data.

Comment: You don't need to optimize yet, you need to write code that works first. I think your code is not doing what you think it is. Look at the results of `sapply(combn(1:3, 2), function(p) {print("function call"); print(p);})`, for instance.

Comment: The code is updated and now works okay. Thanks you guys

Answer (score 1):

Here's your data, transposed because R works well on column-oriented data

```
m <- c("M", "E", "T", "I", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "M", "E", "A", "V", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-",
       "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-",
       "M", "E", "T", "T", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "M", "E", "T", "T", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "M", "E", "T", "I", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "M", "E", "T", "I", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L",
       "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-",
       "M", "E", "T", "I", "S", "L", "I", "T", "I", "L")
m <- t(matrix(m, 10, byrow=TRUE))
```

It seems like you can pull some of your operations outside the loop

```
m[m == "-"] <- NA
notna <- !is.na(m)
```

(and later the multiplication by 100). The basic strategy will be to do a vector operation, where you compare the ith column to *all* the remaining columns in one go, e.g., `colSums(m[, 1] != m[, -1], na.rm=TRUE)`. We do this by pre-allocating a result matrix then iterating over the columns, forming the explicit index of the remaining columns

```
res <- matrix(0, nrow(m) - 1, ncol(m) - 1)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(m) - 1)) {
    idx <- seq(i + 1, ncol(m))
    den <- colSums(notna[, i] & notna[, idx, drop=FALSE])
    res[idx - 1, i] <- colSums(m[,i] != m[, idx, drop=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE) / den
}
res <- 100 * res
```